# About convergence in probability infinitely often.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am confused about the distinction between these two modes of convergence.

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0 $$

$$ P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon\ \text{ i.o }) = 0 $$

Doesn't the first mode of convergence (in probability) imply the second? But apparently it seems the second is more stronger. Maybe my interpretation of "infinitely often" is incorrect. An example of each would be helpful.

Comment: Does "$ \to 0$" mean that the limit is made as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: Corrected, it should be = 0 .

Comment: If $(X_n)$ are independent Bernoulli with $P(X_n=1)=1/n$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$ then $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\to0$ for every positive $\varepsilon$ but $P(|X_n|>\varepsilon\ \text{i.o.})=1$ for every $\varepsilon<1$. So no, the first mode of convergence (in probability) does not imply the second one (almost sure convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Define the event: $$A_n:=\left\{ω\, :\, |X_n(ω)-X(ω)|>ε\right\}$$ Then, by definition $$ω \in A_n \,\,\text{i.o.} \iff ω \in \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n$$ Using this notation your question can be written as (note the questionmark) $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(A_n)=0 \overset{?}\implies P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)=0$$ The answer is no, an example is already given in the comments. The first [Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) gives a *sufficient* (but not necessary) condition for this to hold. However, the following implication is true $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(A_n)>0 \implies P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n)>0$$ or in other words, if they random variables $X_n$ do not converge in probability they cannot converge in the second mode (necessary condition but not sufficient).